# c++ error identifier not found for function?

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

this is my first steps in C++ , and I'm trying to run a function I need to use

but I get this error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C3861   'findAndRotateBlankNumbers': identifier not
>   found ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp   29

and this is the code:

// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum States {
    needBlank,
    needNumber,
    collectNumbers,
};

bool finish = false;
int i = 0;

int main()

{


    char data[] = { "they're 2fast 96 345 6789 a11 24x 2424" };


    printf(data);
    findAndRotateBlankNumbers(data);
    printf(data);

    system("pause");





    return 0;
}


void findAndRotateBlankNumbers(char* ptr) {
    char* first;
    char* last;
    for (uint8_t state = needBlank; *ptr; ptr++) {
        switch (state) {
        case needBlank:
            if (*ptr == ' ') {
                state = needNumber;
            }
            break;
        case needNumber:
            if (isdigit(*ptr)) {
                state = collectNumbers;
                first = ptr;
            }
            else if (*ptr != ' ') {
                state = needBlank;
            }
            break;
        case collectNumbers:
        {
            bool swap = false;
            if (!isdigit(*ptr)) {
                last = ptr - 1;
                state = (*ptr == ' ' ? needNumber : needBlank);
                swap = true;
            }
            else if (!ptr[1]) {
                last = ptr;
                swap = true;
            }
            if (swap) {
                if (last != first) {
                    for (int8_t nums = (last - first + 1) / 2; nums--; ) {
                        char swap = *first;
                        *first++ = *last;
                        *last-- = swap;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }

}
```

what is this ?

---

I have change the order of the code to like you suggested :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

enum States {
    needBlank,
    needNumber,
    collectNumbers,
};

bool finish = false;
int i = 0;

void findAndRotateBlankNumbers(char* ptr) {
    char* first;
    char* last;
    for (uint8_t state = needBlank; *ptr; ptr++) {
        switch (state) {
        case needBlank:
            if (*ptr == ' ') {
                state = needNumber;
            }
            break;
        case needNumber:
            if (isdigit(*ptr)) {
                state = collectNumbers;
                first = ptr;
            }
            else if (*ptr != ' ') {
                state = needBlank;
            }
            break;
        case collectNumbers:
        {
            bool swap = false;
            if (!isdigit(*ptr)) {
                last = ptr - 1;
                state = (*ptr == ' ' ? needNumber : needBlank);
                swap = true;
            }
            else if (!ptr[1]) {
                last = ptr;
                swap = true;
            }
            if (swap) {
                if (last != first) {
                    for (int8_t nums = (last - first + 1) / 2; nums--; ) {
                        char swap = *first;
                        *first++ = *last;
                        *last-- = swap;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }

}

int main()

{


    char data[] = { "they're 2fast 96 345 6789 a11 24x 2424" };


    printf(data);
    findAndRotateBlankNumbers(data);
    printf(data);

    system("pause");





    return 0;
}
```

but now I get other errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C4703   potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'first'
>   used  ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp  52

?

Comment: You need to declare it before using it.

Comment: You need to declare your function before you call it. Either move it up to above the `main`, or declare it by putting `void findAndRotateBlankNumbers(char* ptr);` before `main`.

Comment: I put the function before main function , but now I get other errors:        
   Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C4703 potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'first' used ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp 52

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifier not found error on function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329103/identifier-not-found-error-on-function-call)

Comment: @David12123 compiler is clearly telling `potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'first'` in plain English.

Comment: didn't know I need to "NULL" it..... :-) Thanks , (first time code in C++)

Answer (score 1):

Your function `findAndRotateBlankNumbers` is defined *after* you want to call it in `main`. So the compiler does not know this function exists yet when compiling the main function. To fix this you can either

- move the `findAndRotateBlankNumbers` function *above* `main`
- add the function declaration at the top and leave the definition where it is: `void findAndRotateBlankNumbers(char* ptr);`

As to your second error:

The compiler is complaining that you declare the variable `first` without assigning a value to it at initialization. You should give it a sensible default value like `char* first = nullptr;`

Same with `char* last = nullptr;`

If your compiler does not support `nullptr`, use `NULL` instead;

Comment: I did it , getting new errors - I edit the post - see.